# How can we visualize a dataset with large number of columns? I want to visualize every numeric columns as distplot

Tags: dataframe, data-science, data-visualization

---

```
numeric_data = data.select_dtypes(exclude="O")
numeric_columns = numeric_data.columns
for col in numeric_columns:
    plt.figure()
    sns.distplot(data[col])
```

---

I get this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGBYP.jpg)

I also tried with another approach given below:

---

```
`numeric_data = data.select_dtypes(include="int64")
 numeric_columns = numeric_data.columns
 for col in numeric_columns:
 plt.figure()
 sns.distplot(data[col])`
```

---

Still getting the error.